# Master Shape loses all properties when placed

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I'm trying to create a shape in a stencil that has dynamic properties. When I rotate the Master Shape, I want the two shapes that comprise the master to rotate around each other while retaining their own orientation. Here are pictures of what I'm talking about

[Vertical position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFqft.png)

[Diagonal position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HT3j.png)

I've gotten this to work by setting each shape angle=GUARD(0 deg), but when I pull the collection of shapes into a stencil and then pull it back out all the dynamic features are gone, the two shapes change orientation during rotation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the shapes in the mastershape itself. If they are not in a single group, then Visio will create the group for you automatically on drop, but that one will be a stock group. If you want some custom properties for a shape, you should create that group yourself when you create the mastershape.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Nikolay's answer.  If you want to retain the upright orientation of the sub-shapes, as per your images, you can just add a reference to the parent Angle cell and subtract that value.  For example, in the screenshot below, I've grouped the two shapes and set then set Angle cell of the green sub-shape to:

```
Angle = -Sheet.6!Angle
```

...where 'Sheet.6' is the reference to the group shape.  (The blue sub-shape I've left untouched for comparison.)

[image]